# MacBook Pro RAM Failures when testing with rember

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, crash

I am facing with an interesting problem that; if I use my both memory modules ( 2 x 8gb,1333 ) I am having memory issues and macbook crashes.

I did run some hardware tests (Pressing D during the start up of the machine) and while both modules connected having the issue written something like;

```
Alert! Apple Hardware Test has detected an error.

4MEM/9/40000000 0x84e9dc18
```

If I repeat the tests over and over again while both memory modules inserted; having the same issue with the last hex part (I assume it is the address on the module) different.

I am running the "Rember" tool to test the memory as well and again if both modules inserted it is failing but there is no issue so far while only one slot is being used.

Tested different slots with same module as well to understand if the issue is with the slot. But no luck (if I can call this luck. LoL) to reproduce the issue.

p.s : On all my tests (I did see 2 times different errors related to HDD (Samsung Pro SSD series).

Is there anything else (a tool a missing test etc..) I can try to see whats going on here with my machine guys ?

edit :

```
Model  : MacBook Pro (17-inch, Late 2011)
OS Version  : Sierra 10.12.6 (16G29)
Memory Brand : Corsair 8GB (per modeule)
```

> Problem started to happen on since 4 days. (I just closed the the
>   screen down and put it into my bag). When I took it out at the airport
>   to show it working to security guards I saw it was too hot. And then
>   observe the problem.

Comment: Sorry to hear you're having problems. Can I suggest you [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/295239/edit) your question to include some additional details. In particular, I think adding your exact Mac model, version of macOS and, if known, the exact brand details of your memory modules will help you get the best answer possible. Also, how long has this been happening? Did the start of this behaviour coincide with anything else (e.g. software update, new hardware, etc)?

Comment: Based on what you described, it sounds like a failing logic board (memory controller) or a failing CPU (with an integrated memory controller).   You best bet is to test the memory in a *different* machine (if possible) or try different memory.  If the problem persists, it's time to look at either a new CPU or new logic board.

Comment: @Allan thanks for the comment. I hope I wont need a new logic controller but possibly I will end up with it. Around 2 years ago Apple changed the board because of factory out problem.

Comment: I just saw your edit re:  2011 MBP and coincidentally, I have a [YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ecEPLYbjXXU) of a repair of a 2011 logic board playing in the background in which the tech says this model is "cancerous."  I hope you can get it resolved inexpensively.  This model is infamous for it's GPU issues.

Comment: Exactly it was with the original boards. Then they changed the board with a fixed one (at least what has been told to me so). I ll see official service when I go back to hometown.

Comment: OMG...in the video, the tech was showing the $700USD "replacement" board from Apple was actually a badly reworked board that failed right after having the video fixed.  I hope you get good results with the official service center.

Comment: Lol, I went for more than 2 years with it. But obviously still some issues but I am still suspicious about the overheat caused something. Also some over load of current on the memory modules caused issues on the memory. May be a quick rubber trick could make it working as it was before. Some reports says so. And soon I ll sell this one and switch to a 2016 version without touchbar.

Comment: Please do not use tag (mac-pro) on questions about MacBook Pro. Editing...

Comment: Intersting that yesterday, I took out one of the suspected ram module and looked at the golden connection part. Saw a little white sticky ( don't know how it got to there) piece. Cleared it gently and put it back. From that point on, I tried Rember one more time and no issues. Tried second time and failed. Tried again and saw no issues again. Still investigating. This is a kinda do-or-die hobby from now on :)